# Postgres datatype conversion differ on Ubuntu and windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, ubuntu, sqldatatypes

I am getting following exception on windows while running the below

> ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric = character varying Hint: No  operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts." while executing with query parameter

I am passing the Numeric String for parameter using function as a named parameter to the query

```
getUIDCount(String id) {
 ...

select count(UID) as icrd FROM UID_tbl WHERE id = ? 
 ...
 }
```

> > where id is numeric(5,0)" in table

Everything works well on Ubuntu but getting Error while running the same code on windows. I have to do the explicit casting just for windows. I am using PostgreSQL 9.4.3. I am using "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialec" and grails 2.3.11 with runtime  'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'

> updated with how it is getting called

```
def Integer getUIDSetSize(String _id)
{ 
   Integer i = 0; 
   Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource); 
   String sqlt = """select count(UID) as icrd FROM UID_tbl WHERE _id = ?"""; 
  log.trace(sqlt); 
  sql.eachRow(sqlt, [_id], { row -> i = row.icrd; }); 
  return i; 
 }
```

> > This how it get called def _id1 = params._id1; count1 = HelperService.getUIDSetSize(_id1)

Comment: You dont need the quotes for numeric datatypes. (and if you do need quotes, you need single quotes)

Comment: Please add the error you are getting without cast

Comment: `"1234567"` is a column name, **not** a string literal. Your query will result in an error message: `column "1234567" does not exist` (unless you _do_ have a column named `1234567` which I highly doubt

Comment: @Santosh Then it's quite clear: you're sending a string even though the column is numeric. Don't send them as strings

Comment: @sami-kuhmonen but the same query works on Ubuntu

Comment: @Santosh Edit the question to be *exactly* as you have it. In the question you have no parameters, whereas in this you are using parameters, so all information is not given.

Comment: Sounds as if you are passing different values in the two environments. A string literal on one system and proper number on the other. What exactly is the (Java) code you use to run the query? And what exactly is the value you are passing to the query in both environments

Comment: Don't add code in comments. **Edit** your question.

Answer (score 0):

> > The workaround for casting from varchar to numeric is

```
CREATE CAST(VARCHAR AS NUMERIC) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
```

> This is not the best solution and would suggest selective casting from the code.